# How can I make UIButton disable which is created programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created some buttons in my code. I want to set it disable but I'm not sure how. here's my code.

```
UIButton *btn_levels = [UIButton    buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn_levels.frame=CGRectMake(x-10, y, 40, 40);
[btn_levels setTitle:[beginer_lvl objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_levels addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn_levels.tag =i;

btn_levels.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
btn_levels.tintColor=[UIColor cyanColor];

NSLog(@"btn nm=%@",[beginer_lvl objectAtIndex:i]);

[self.scroll addSubview:btn_levels];
```

and that is the button method but I don't know what to do...

```
-(void)btn_Method
{
    //to make button disable
}
```

Comment: Disable after it's tapped? What methods does `UIButton` offer that you have looked at and seem appropriate? Also, have you looked at the target:action docs and the callback method spec?

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line

```
[btn_levels addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and this method

```
-(void)btn_Method:(UIButton*)sender
{
  sender.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the statement

```
[btn_levels addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[btn_levels addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Also change the below method -

```
-(void)btn_Method
{
    //to make button disable
}
```

to

```
-(void)btn_Method:(UIButton*)button
{
    //to make button disable
    [button setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disabled but visible

```
btn_levels.enabled = NO;
```

also invisible

```
btn_levels.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: thnks ...but what should i do if i wanna disable only one button and others are enable...?

Comment: Ok,  so the problem is probably that you do not have access to programatically created buttons in the method's scope. 
Well you need to have instance variables defined in the view controller to have them accessible from various methods.

Comment: @EarlGrey No my friend..look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Target actions can send the object for which it'll performed the action. To make your method to know which button was tap, you need to make its definition to get the button inside the method. So just change you button definition to look like this,

```
- (void) btn_Method:(UIButton *)sender {...}
```

also, where you're adding target to the button you've to add a colon ( **:** ) *after the method name* to tell the compiler that, this action will need an object on which an action was added. So that line should look like this,

```
[btn_levels addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_Method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                                      ^
```

Here, we will get a `sender` (you can give any name to your argument) of type `UIButton` with btn_Method action call. That's it, now you can do anything with that button, so in your case you want to make it disable, so the method would look like this,

```
- (void) btn_Method:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.enabled = NO;
}
```